# What is the difference between /GL and /LTCG in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, hyperlink

I tried looking online for the differences but couldn't get a lot. The two options sound related to each other:

[/LTCG](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/ltcg-link-time-code-generation)

> The /LTCG option tells the linker to call the compiler and perform whole-program optimization.

[/GL](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/reference/gl-whole-program-optimization)

> Enables whole program optimization.

Does anybody know the exact difference?

Comment: Noteworthy information from the documentation in the first link you provided "/LTCG is implied with /GL."

Comment: Agreed, but does it mean /GL does something more than /LTCG?

Comment: Noteworthy information from the documentation in the second link you provided "If you compile your program with /GL and /c, you should use the /LTCG linker option to create the output file."

Comment: I'm not an expert on the matter otherwise I'd leave an answer; I just quickly looked through the documentation.

Comment: It looks like the key is that "/GL also makes profile guided optimization available; see /LTCG."

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just realized. The main difference that /gl is a compiler option and /ltcg is a linker option.

Comment: I actually just added an answer stating that as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`/GL` is a compiler option and `/LTCG` is a linker option. According to the documentation they are closely related to each other. For example:

> `/LTCG` is implied with `/GL`

However, `/LTCG` can be employed without using `/GL`.

> The `/LTCG` option tells the linker to call the compiler and perform whole-program optimization. You can also do profile guided optimization.

How is profile guided optimization enabled? By using the `/GL` option.

> `/GL` also makes profile guided optimization available; see `/LTCG`

What is profile guided optimization? Here's a snippet from the start of the [profile guided optimization documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k32f4k.aspx):

> Profile-guided optimization lets you optimize an output file, where the optimizer uses data from test runs of the .exe or .dll file. The data represents how the program is likely to perform in a production environment.