# How can I optimize just one function if optimization is switched off for the whole project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022

I work on a large project which has optimization disabled.  The vast majority of the devs prefer it this way because our project is I/O bound anyway and it makes dump analysis easier.  Recently I've started looking replacing our `printf` based tracing mechanism with `std::format`.  However, there's a problem, in my profiling, std::format is faster than our current tracing with optimization on but more than 2000% slower with optimization off.  Using it would actually make a significant performance dent.

This has lead me to wonder if I could turn optimization on for just one function or perhaps just one static library.  However, I'm struggling to work out how.  The problem is that the nature `std::format` means that any tracing function you wrote to use it would have to forward on the template arguments and must therefore be a template its self.  E.g.:

```
template<typename... Args>
void Trace(std::_Fmt_wstring<Args& ...> fmt, Args& ...args)
{
    wchar_t buf[0x1000];
    std::format_to(buf, fmt, args...);
    // Pass the buffer to the tracing framework
}
```

Because it's a template, it's header based and I can't put the compiled tracing code in a static library.  It'll get instantiated in the non-optimized code where it's called.

How can I make this function optimized?  I've tried `#pragma optimize` however it doesn't help because I need to not only optimize the function its self but the code generated by `std::format_to`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Modern standard library features are often implemented assuming optimizations will be applied. Consequently they may insert debugging instrumentation or extra levels of abstraction which are quite slow with the rational that it is ok since they will be removed or inlined during compilation. Sometimes you can remove these with defines but not always. Releasing unoptimized builds will probably continue to become less and less practical.

Comment: And this "debugging instrumentation" may add extra members to containers and iterators, making debug and realease versions having different memory layouts. I expect that it will be extremely hard to make the plan work, on the border of impossible.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I take your point and I’ve advocated to turn it on in the past.  I wouldn’t have thought merely turning off the optimzer would do *all *of the things you mention though.  It’s not an actual debug build with debug pre-processor entries etc.

Comment: With optimizations completely disabled I wouldn't be surprised if even something as simple as a vector index lookup will cause several layers deep of function calls, probably each with stack copies of the arguments as well, (not even considering additional debug instrumentation). The way C++ works, it kind of assumes that a compiler will at least perform inlining of small functions. Otherwise I wouldn't be surprised if any, especially class/template based code, would produce on the order of 10x or more larger binaries and slower execution. At that point, why use C++ over e.g. Python?

Comment: @user17732522 Sure, although amazingly our product has been like this for 15 years and performance testing continues to show a fairly small impact despite pretty widespread use of modern c++.  We’re not a very performance intensive application and the main reason why use c++ is because of deep integration with the OS.

Comment: @Benj Well, I guess good luck then. I don't know about MSVC, but my guess is that the only workable solution is to use the explicit instantiation approach on `Trace`, which may not be in the interest of your tracing solution given that it limits the set of argument types. That way you can optimize the translation unit with the instantiations only. (This may also require wrapping and explicitly instantiating `std::_Fmt_wstring` in your own class template for the same reason.)

Comment: @Benj I'm not surprised that the impact would be so severe. `std::format` looks like an ideal candidate for optimizations. It uses a parameter pack of various types, which implies heavy use of template metaprogramming shenanigans and `constexpr`. This almost always implies deep recursion, leading to frequent deep call stacks. With optimizations, these might not just be inlined, but recursion can be tail-call optimized in some cases, which can have a huge impact. Additionally, you lose constant folding which means some values that are in theory constant may now be evaluated every time.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm not familiar with this aspect, but if you optimize only one translation unit, won't that introduce ABI incompatibilities?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That may be the case for MSVC as was hinted at by other comments above, but I am not very familiar with it. For GCC and Clang I am not aware that ABI is affected in any way, either on the core language level or the standard library level, by the optimization level.

Comment: The option can be set for each individual source file in a project.  So moving the code that needs to be optimized is a simple approach.  Do keep in mind that the runtime support libraries play a role as well, the debug build (/MDd) has a lot of asserts to help diagnose bad calls.  So you also want to check the effects of selecting /MD, applied to the entire project.

Comment: Other possible title: "How to change optimization level for specific template functions from third-party headers?" I think that's better than the current title in that it mentions the template and third-party header part. Ie. Implies you prefer not to have to edit third-party header files. Also, If you don't particularly care about having to write a lot of code to achieve it, you could narrow the scope to a single template function (don't use plural).

Answer (score 3):

> The vast majority of the devs prefer it this way because our project is I/O bound anyway and it makes dump analysis easier

This is what the [/Zo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zo-enhance-optimized-debugging?view=msvc-170) flag was invented to solve for. It makes debugging retail code way easier. Not perfect, but far better than without it.

Comment: Thanks, I have used this at a previous company and it does make quite a big difference.  This probably is the way we should ultimately go.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that one challenge is that they're template functions. You could try wrapping the library headers with your own headers that declare the specific specializations that you use as [`extern`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_instantiation) (to prevent implicit instantiation of the templates when they get used), and then create a static library where you instantiate those specializations, and compile the static library with whichever optimization level you want (I'm not that familiar with MSVC, but you might need to check whether there are any compatibility needs of which runtime libraries are being linked to in the static library and your own compiled binaries). Then in your project, you include your wrapped versions of the library headers and link against the static library.

Using `extern` templates was something I learned about from [this blog post by Daniele Pallastrelli](https://arne-mertz.de/2019/02/extern-template-reduce-compile-times/), which used the technique to avoid duplicate template instantiations in multiple translation units to decrease compilation times.

Comment: Thanks, this worked really well.  The only caveat was that I had to turn off "Whole program optimization" (/GL).  This delays code generation until link time and when you have optimization off in the calling code, this effectively causes optimization to be off in static libraries that extern code too.  In effect, the setting becomes "Whole program de-optimization".

Comment: Are you aware of `/LTCG`? https://stackoverflow.com/q/35471658/20170164

Comment: I am, although neither option is very well documented from the point of view of what happens when you have different options selected for different compilation units.  I'm getting some strange results which don't seem to be documented where the setting from one compilation unit will affect others.